# Height of bootstrap button changes with additional span

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons) to create all button elements on our website.

The button height is created using line-height, which also helps with centering the text.

I want to include two different font sizes in one button. The standard size, and a smaller note. I have created a very stripped down version of this [here with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eAZCN/)

This is the html.

```
<div class="button">
    test
    <small>(note)</small>
</div>
```

This is the CSS.

```
.button {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

small {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

The issue is that the height of the button gets increased by 4 pixels. Removing the smaller text, will again bring the button to it's correct height. How can solve this problem as I cannot have a higher button?

Having a fixed height attribute of 60px does not work either, because then the text is not centered vertically anymore.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets OK (on chrome) if you add a `vertical-align` to your `small` tag

http://jsfiddle.net/eAZCN/3/

```
.button {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.button small {
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:10px;
}
```

Comment: It is better but still 62px high.

Comment: I played with your answer some more. The vertical-align is actually not needed at all. Only setting the line-height is required. This does not make sense to me though. Why 10px? But in either case: thank you very much.